# Mongodb connect-mongo session store multiple app on same db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, sails.js, connect-mongo

I have two SailsJS apps that use connect-mongo to store sessions. They are connected to the same MongoDB database and the problem it's when I am connected to the first app, if I go on the second app I'm directly disconnected on the first app and vice versa. I don't know how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to keep the sessions from your two apps totally distinct?

I think where you set up your session storage in `/config/session.js`, you can name the collection used for session storage. Why not use a different name for each of your two apps?

```
adapter: 'mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017,
db: mydb,
collection: 'sessions', // Use a different name for each app here
```